# Installing omniauth in an old application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, omniauth

I checked omniauth dependencies and there are just two gems: hashie and rack.

I also checked hashie and rack dependencies, which are none.

But when I add `gem 'omniauth'` to my Gemfile, and run bundle I get, omitting output for brevity:

```
Installing multipart-post (1.2.0) 
Installing faraday (0.8.8) 
Installing httpauth (0.2.0) 
Installing mini_portile (0.5.1) 
Installing multi_json (1.8.0) 
Installing nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Where that installations comes from? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: What versions of omniauth, hashie, and rack are involved?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by another gem requiring an old version of hashie, so I updated it:

```
bundle update twitter
```

And then bundle succeed.